# Android FCM badge didn't working in background

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, badge

I want to update badge in background and I use notification style, but it didn't work. I don't want to use data style because only one notification appeared.
Please help I want check push in back ground and update badge

```
public void zzm(Intent intent) {

    Set<String> keys = intent.getExtras().keySet();
    for (String key : keys) {
        try {

            if (key.equals("badge")) {
                String cnt = intent.getExtras().get(key).toString();
                int badgeCount = Integer.valueOf(cnt);
                ShortcutBadger.applyCount(this, badgeCount);

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.i("uniqbadge", "zzm Custom_FirebaseMessagingService" + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    super.zzm(intent);
}
```

//this is received code

```
  public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

        showNotification(remoteMessage.getData().get("title"), remoteMessage.getData().get("message"));

        set_alarm_badge();
        }
```

//my notification setting

```
  private void showNotification(String title, String message) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(message)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());

    }
```

// this is my badge update

```
public void set_alarm_badge(){
    Context context=getApplicationContext();
    Intent launchIntent = context.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(context.getPackageName());
    Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.BADGE_COUNT_UPDATE");


    MainActivity.badge_count++;
    intent.putExtra("badge_count", MainActivity.badge_count);
    intent.putExtra("badge_count_package_name",getApplicationContext().getPackageName());
    intent.putExtra("badge_count_class_name",MainActivity.class.getName());

        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT> Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD_MR1) {
        intent.setFlags(0x00000020);
    }
    if (canResolveBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), intent)) {
        Log.d("TAG", "hi ");
        getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(intent);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
@Override
public void handleIntent(Intent intent) {
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
    // get your badge key from bundle
    ShortcutBadger.applyCount(this, "Your Badge Count");
    sendNotification(intent);
}
```

Just override this method in FirebaseMessagingService and it will work even the app is in foreground, background or killed. No need of extra service or alarm it is method from FCM.

Comment: With firebase-messaging 17.3.4 I get error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype

Comment: onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) will work in background for 17 but you have to modify your notification and send "data" in notification rather than "notification" as mentioned in google fcm doc.

Comment: Yes, I override onMessageReceived which works now, but I also found that you have to add this to your manifest:
<service android:name=".MyMessagingService" android:exported="false">
<intent-filter>
       <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
</intent-filter>
</service>

Comment: obviously you have to provide the service in manifest. Its great you get it :)

Comment: you just saved my day